# Correct http error code if id passed in body not exists/invalid?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

What is the correct http error code if id indicated in body not exists?

Example: The cityId 123 does not exists in database

```
POST /profiles
{
    "name":"foo",
    "cityId":123
}
```

Is it 404? 400? or 422?

Comment: Take a look: http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/error-handling-in-rest-api-with-jersey/

Answer (score 8):

It's up to you in the end, but I'd say 422.

400 implies that the request is malformed, which isn't the case. The request is perfectly valid lexically, hence why you can parse and process it OK.

http://www.restpatterns.org/HTTP_Status_Codes/400_-_Bad_Request

404 implies that the URL requested does not exist. The resource (i.e. the web service endpoint) does exist. I might suggest a different answer if the id was part of the URL, i.e. in a query string. 404s refer to the URL only in my experience, not to POSTed bodies. Also note that the link below refers to 404s only in the context of the URL, not the contents of the POST body.

http://www.restpatterns.org/HTTP_Status_Codes/404_-_Not_Found

Therefore this leaves 422 as the only valid candidate.

http://www.restpatterns.org/HTTP_Status_Codes/422_-_Unprocessable_Entity

Another poster suggested 204, but this is incorrect because the request has been processed, but has not been successful. All 2** status codes imply some level of success.

http://www.restpatterns.org/HTTP_Status_Codes/204_-_No_Content

Answer (score 4):

Your are using RESTful web service based on HTTP, so you should follow HTTP specifications (RFC 7231, RFC 4918, RFC 2616).

- [400 Bad Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1)

  > The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or
  > will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be
  > a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request
  > message framing, or deceptive request routing).
- [404 Not Found](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4)

  > The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did
  > not find a current representation for the target resource or is not
  > willing to disclose that one exists.  A 404 status code does not
  > indicate whether this lack of representation is temporary or
  > permanent; the 410 (Gone) status code is preferred over 404 if the
  > origin server knows, presumably through some configurable means, that
  > the condition is likely to be permanent.

  and older but more clear, see [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.5):

  > The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address. This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other response is applicable.
- [422 Unprocessable Entity](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2)

  > The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
  > understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
  > 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
  > syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request)
  > status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
  > instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML
  > request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but
  > semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

I would say, the best matching HTTP status code is 422, because the URI exists, the syntax of request is correct, but semantically erroneous.